# Draw linklist using svg - jquery svg

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, svg

I am new to svg so I am not sure how to implement as I want to render different data structures to the user using svg dynamically. I have made an attempt for linkedlist as :

```
 <svg width="640" height="480" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">

                    <g>
                  <title>Layer 1</title>
                  <path id="svg_1" d="m92,60l131,0l0,49l-131,0l0,-49z" stroke-linecap="null" stroke-linejoin="null" stroke-dasharray="null" stroke-width="5" stroke="#000000" fill="#FF0000"/>
                  <text xml:space="preserve" text-anchor="middle" font-family="serif" font-size="24" id="svg_4" y="93" x="179" opacity="0.5" stroke-linecap="null" stroke-linejoin="null" stroke-dasharray="null" stroke-width="0" stroke="#000000" fill="#000000"/>
                  <line id="svg_5" y2="108" x2="163" y1="60" x1="163" stroke-linecap="null" stroke-linejoin="null" stroke-dasharray="null" stroke-width="5" stroke="#000000" fill="none"/>
                  <text xml:space="preserve" text-anchor="middle" font-family="serif" font-size="24" id="svg_6" y="84" x="109" opacity="0.5" stroke-linecap="null" stroke-linejoin="null" stroke-dasharray="null" stroke-width="0" stroke="#000000" fill="#000000"/>
                  <text xml:space="preserve" text-anchor="middle" font-family="serif" font-size="24" id="svg_7" y="86" x="138" opacity="0.5" stroke-linecap="null" stroke-linejoin="null" stroke-dasharray="null" stroke-width="0" stroke="#000000" fill="#000000"/>
                  <text xml:space="preserve" text-anchor="middle" font-family="serif" font-size="24" id="svg_8" y="106" x="135" opacity="0.5" stroke-linecap="null" stroke-linejoin="null" stroke-dasharray="null" stroke-width="0" stroke="#000000" fill="#000000"/>
                  <text xml:space="preserve" text-anchor="middle" font-family="serif" font-size="24" id="svg_9" y="21" x="-532" opacity="0.5" stroke-linecap="null" stroke-linejoin="null" stroke-dasharray="null" stroke-width="0" stroke="#000000" fill="#000000"/>
                  <text xml:space="preserve" text-anchor="middle" font-family="serif" font-size="24" id="svg_10" y="101" x="140" opacity="0.5" stroke-linecap="null" stroke-linejoin="null" stroke-dasharray="null" stroke-width="0" stroke="#000000" fill="#000000"/>
                  <text xml:space="preserve" text-anchor="middle" font-family="serif" font-size="24" id="svg_11" y="103" x="121" opacity="0.5" stroke-linecap="null" stroke-linejoin="null" stroke-dasharray="null" stroke-width="0" stroke="#000000" fill="#000000"/>
                  <text xml:space="preserve" text-anchor="middle" font-family="serif" font-size="24" id="svg_12" y="106" x="473" opacity="0.5" stroke-linecap="null" stroke-linejoin="null" stroke-dasharray="null" stroke-width="5" stroke="#000000" fill="#FF0000"/>
                  <rect id="svg_13" height="52" width="122" y="58" x="283" stroke-linecap="null" stroke-linejoin="null" stroke-dasharray="null" stroke-width="5" stroke="#000000" fill="#FF0000"/>
                  <line id="svg_14" y2="109" x2="358" y1="60" x1="357" stroke-linecap="null" stroke-linejoin="null" stroke-dasharray="null" stroke-width="5" stroke="#000000" fill="none"/>
                  <line id="svg_18" y2="103" x2="360" y1="65" x1="401" stroke-linecap="null" stroke-linejoin="null" stroke-dasharray="null" stroke-width="5" stroke="#000000" fill="none"/>
                  <line id="svg_19" y2="101" x2="403" y1="66" x1="357" stroke-linecap="null" stroke-linejoin="null" stroke-dasharray="null" stroke-width="5" stroke="#000000" fill="none"/>
                  <line id="svg_21" y2="82" x2="281" y1="82" x1="222" stroke-linecap="null" stroke-linejoin="null" stroke-dasharray="null" stroke-width="5" stroke="#000000" fill="none"/>
                  <path id="svg_24" d="m258,61l24,21l-23,26l-1,-47z" stroke-linecap="null" stroke-linejoin="null" stroke-dasharray="null" stroke-width="5" stroke="#000000" fill="#bfbfbf"/>
                  <path id="svg_25" d="m258,60" opacity="0.5" stroke-linecap="null" stroke-linejoin="null" stroke-dasharray="null" stroke-width="5" stroke="#000000" fill="#FF0000"/>
                 </g>   
 </svg>
```

Above svg is a static linkedlist with no value in nodes. Now there are two problems in this :

- How can I make this linked list dynamic?
- Is there a way to write text in rectangle other then positioning the text in the rectangle

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/PMxc8/

Edit : Is jquery svg good idea to go.

Thanks

Comment: check out http://d3js.org/

Comment: @epoch unfortunately I can not use a library for this.

Comment: mmh, thats going to be hard, you will have to learn javascript then, only way to make it dynamic

Comment: Can I ask why no libraries ? Just it may help understand what what some of the issues are.

Comment: @Ian page already have too much files loading. Cant afford one more library to load.

Comment: What do you actually want to happen dynamically ?

Comment: @Ian - I want to make different data structures such as doubly linked list etc. and the input for this will come from user. Can I use jquery svg for this.

Answer (score 0):

in order to make svg dynamically, you can create svg elements using JavaScript. check below functions. they will create svg elements dynamically.

```
var SVG_NAMESPACE_URI = 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg';

function createNode (type, attributes) {
                        var node = document.createElementNS(SVG_NAMESPACE_URI, type);
                        if (type === 'image')
                                attributes.preserveAspectRatio = 'none';
                        if (typeof attributes !== undefined)
                                setAttributes(node, attributes);
                        return node
                }

function setAttributes(el, attributes) {
                        for (var attribute in attributes) {
                                if (attributes[attribute] != null)
                                        el.setAttribute(attribute, attributes[attribute]);
                        }
                }
```

**//usage//**

```
var path1 =createNode('path',{
id:'svg_1',
d:'m92,60l131,0l0,49l-131,0l0,-49z',
'stroke-width':"5",
 stroke:"#000000",
fill:"#FF0000"
});
```

now you got the path, append it to main svg. like

```
document.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0].appendChild(path1);
```

similarly create other svg elements one by one.